# Не подключается к базе данных на openserver

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sqlite, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Смотрел курс, там показывали как подключиться к базе данных таким образом:
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=practices; charset=utf-8;', 'mysql', 'mysql');
$aboutData = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM about");

Но у меня выдает ошибку:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set in C:\OSPanel\domains\test[sharewood.biz] template\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\test[sharewood.biz] template\index.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'mysql', 'mysql') #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\test[sharewood.biz] template\index.php on line 2

Вот база данных. Все это на openserver
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибка во время подключения. Проверьте пароль и логин подключения

Comment: Эта ошибка говорит про кодировку charset=utf8 , убери дефис перед восьмёркой.